# How to fix an Objects are not valid as a React child Error?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I am very new to programming with React-native, and I was wondering if anyone could explain how I should fix this error? I was following along with a tutorial and had an error come up due to this section of code, even though it matched the tutorial code.

Here is the section of code:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext } from "react";
import * as Google from "expo-google-app-auth";

const AuthContext = createContext({});
export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const signInWithGoogle = async() => {
    await Google.logInAsync
  }
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user: null,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
export default function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

These other two sections may be relevant as well:

Root of the App:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, SafeAreaView, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import AuthProvider from "./hooks/useAuth";
import StackNavigator from "./StackNavigator";
import { NavigationContainer} from "@react-navigation/native";

// Function for creating button

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AuthProvider>
        <StackNavigator />
      </AuthProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

This is my code for the Login Screen:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import useAuth from '../hooks/useAuth';

const LoginScreen = () => {
  const { user } = useAuth();
  console.log(user);
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>
              Login to the app
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
};
export default LoginScreen
```

This is the error that appears:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Comment: It looks like what you're passing in as `children` is an object (like `{}`) and not React elements. How are you calling `AuthProvider`?

Comment: @Roy J  I edited the question above with more information.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you auth with firebase. it makes easier this things.